# Laravel Mailgun email Takes 10 seconds to send

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun

I've setup Mailgun to send emails. They are going but each email is taking ~10 seconds. What might the reason be for this? Is there something wrong or does it typically take this long?

Sending emails with Laravel queue returns responses quickly and email is sent in the background. I am expecting the same behavior from Mailgun.

If Mailgun is taking 10 seconds then there is no need to use it because Laravel itself takes this time to send email directly. Shouldn't Mailgun send an email immediately? Please guide me if someone knows the reason.

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mailgun_domain
MAILGUN_SECRET=mailgun_secret
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mailgun_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=mailgun_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

Comment: Regardless if it should take 10s or not, using a transactional email service (such as Mailgun) is definitely recommended for email deliverability.

Comment: Are you using a queue?

Comment: No, sending emails directly.

Comment: 10s isn't a huge deal, just push emails into a queue in the background and move on from there